# Tracking the meeting invitation response in OutLook and Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I, have a requirement where I, have to send an email invitation to the mail. The user can Accept and decline the response in the email. I, have completed the user email invitation and adding to the calendar either in Gmail or outlook using the **.ics** file. Here is the code for the inviation email

```
filePath = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Email/calenderInvitation.ics");
                fileContent = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath).ReadToEnd();
                fileContent = fileContent.Replace("#TO#", receiver);
                fileContent = fileContent.Replace("#FROM#", fromAddress.Address);
                fileContent = fileContent.Replace("#LOCATION#", eventVenue);
                fileContent = fileContent.Replace("#UID#", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""));
                fileContent = fileContent.Replace("#CREATED-AT#", Convert.ToDateTime(meetingDate).ToString(TimeFormat));
                fileContent = fileContent.Replace("#DTSTART#", Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).ToString(TimeFormat));
                fileContent = fileContent.Replace("#DTEND#", Convert.ToDateTime(finishTime).ToString(TimeFormat));


                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress.Address);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(receiver));
                message.Subject = string.Format("{0}  {1} @ {2} {3} {4} {5} - {6}", "Invitation: ", meetingTypeName,
                    Convert.ToDateTime(meetingDate).ToString("dddd"), Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).ToString("MMMM"),
                    Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).ToString("yyyy"), startTime,
                    finishTime);

                var iCalendarContentType = new ContentType("text/calendar; method=REQUEST");

                var calendarView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(fileContent, iCalendarContentType);
                calendarView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
                message.AlternateViews.Add(calendarView);
                smtp.Send(message);
```

Here is the screen shot of the email.

[image: Email Inviatation]

Now I want to track the response from the user whether they have click ACCEPT/DECLINE

While research I found this links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633669(v=exchg.80).aspx

However this will work on outlook or office 365. But I need the response from other email as well like GMAIL etc

Here is the .ics file format

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//A//B//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":mailto:#FROM#
ATTENDEE;CN="Attendee";CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=
 NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:#TO#
DTSTART:#DTSTART#
DTEND:#DTEND#
LOCATION:#LOCATION#
SUMMARY: Invitation for Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:#UID#
DTSTAMP:#CREATED-AT#
CREATED:#CREATED-AT#
LAST-MODIFIED:#CREATED-AT#
DESCRIPTION:Test description\n
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Did you got any solution?